# The matrix $f(A)$ has the eigenvalues $f(\lambda_k)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with $A\cdot A^{\star}=A^{\star}\cdot A$ and $U$ unitary, i.e. $U^{\star}\cdot U=U\cdot U^{\star}=I$, with $U^{\star}AU=\text{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots , \lambda_n)$, where $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. Let $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^mc_kz^k$.

I want to show that the matrix $f(A)$ has the eigenvalues $f(\lambda_k), \ k=1, \ldots , n$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

$$f(A)v_j=\left (\sum_{k=0}^mc_kA^k\right )v_j=\sum_{k=0}^mc_kA^kv_j=\sum_{k=0}^mc_k\lambda_j^kv_j=\left (\sum_{k=0}^mc_k\lambda_j^k\right )v_j=f(\lambda_j)v_j$$

But in this way I haven't used any given information about the matrix $A$. So, have I done something wrong?

Comment: For sure you have used the fact, that $\lambda_j$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $v_j$. Your proof looks good.

Comment: But I haven't used the fact that $A\cdot A^{\star}=A^{\star}\cdot A$ or that $U^{\star}AU=\text{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots , \lambda_n)$, where $U$ is unitary, have I? Do we not need this information? @Fakemistake

Comment: @MaryStar Did you read my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You proved correctly that every $f(\lambda_k)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(A)$, but you did *not* prove that it has no other eigenvalues. That's where the other hypothesis are needed.

Comment: Ah I see! How could we prove this? Could you give me a hint?

Comment: @MaryStar Sure. Your matrix $A$ is normal. Use the spectral theorem.

Comment: Doesn't the spectral theorem states that any symmetric matrix is diagonalizable? How could we use that? I got stuck right now. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: @MaryStar The spectral theorem says that every normal matrix is diagonalizable with respect to an orthonormal bais. I forgot that, in this case, you are already assuming that. Please use that fact.

Comment: But how can we use the fact that $A=UDU^{\star}$, where $D=\text{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots , \lambda_n)$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Since $U$ is unitary, $U^\star=U^{-i}$. Therefore, $f(A)=f(UDU^{-1})=Uf(D)U^{-1}$ and $f(D)=\operatorname{diag}\bigl(f(\lambda_1),\ldots,f(\lambda_n)\bigr)$.

Comment: Does it hold that $$f(D)=\sum_{k=0}^mc_kD^k=\sum_{k=0}^mc_k\text{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots , \lambda_n)^k=\sum_{k=0}^mc_k\text{diag}(\lambda_1^k, \ldots , \lambda_n^k)=\text{diag}(\sum_{k=0}^mc_k\lambda_1^k, \ldots , \sum_{k=0}^mc_k\lambda_n^k)=\text{diag}(f(\lambda_1), \ldots , f(\lambda_n))$$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, it does.

Comment: Great! So, we have that $$f(A)=U\text{diag}(f(\lambda_1), \ldots , f(\lambda_n)) U^{-1}$$ But how can we conclude that the only eigenvalues of $f(A)$ are these $f(\lambda_k)$ ? I don't see this yet.

Comment: @MaryStar This shows that $f(A)$ is similar to $\operatorname{diag}\bigl(f(\lambda_1),\ldots,f(\lambda_n)\bigr)$. And the only eigenvalues of this matrix are $f(\lambda_1),\ldots,f(\lambda_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$, then
$$
f(A)=f(UDU^*)=Uf(D)U^*
$$

Comment: Why does the second equality hold? We have that $$f(A)=f(UDU^{\star})=\sum_{k=0}^mc_k(UDU^{\star})^k$$ How could we continue?

Comment: @MaryStar $(UDU^*)^k=UD^kU^*$ (by induction on $k$).